# How to return array length in class method in php?

Tags: php, arrays, methods

I have an array:

```
$data = array("a", "b", "c");
```

I'm trying to print out the length of this array (3) in a class method

```
class MyString {
    public $myChars;
    public $length;

    function __construct($data) {
        $this->myChars = $data;
    }

    function length() {
        $length = count($this->myChars);
        return $length;
    }
```

Calling it from:

```
$mystring = new MyString($data);
```

But this doesn't work...

Comment: Thats because you have only called the constructor and not the `length()` method

Comment: Don't you just need to then call `$count = $mystring->length()` or similar? What exactly isn't working? What are you expecting, and what are you actually getting.

Comment: I would encourage you to read [PHP: Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: Note that you're not actually using `$this->length`, you might want to set it in the constructor (and when it changes), and use it in `length()`.

Comment: Thank you all for fast replies! Got it working with Halayem Anis' answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$mystring = new MyString($data);
print $mystring->length();
```

Answer (score 0):

Some modifications to your class :

```
class MyString {
    public $myChars;
    public $length;

    public function __construct($data) {
       $this->myChars = $data;
    }

    public function length() {
       $this->length = count($this->myChars);
       return $this->$length;
    }
}
```

Use like that :

```
$mystring = new MyString($data);
print $mystring->length();
```